# Dynamically set the width of a view in inches

Tags: android, android-layout

It's possible to set a layout width in inches using the input.xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="3in">
```

How can I do this programmatically?

Comment: Short answer is No. You shouldn't be building your layouts based on inches anyhow, with so many screen sizes and resolutions it is bound to be a nightmare if you are trying to convert everything to real world inches. See [Supporting Multiple Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for best practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use:

```
float pixels = TypedValue.applyDimension(
    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_IN, 3, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

to calculate the size in pixels for 3" on your device and then set a layout width.

Comment: getResources is a method.  getResources().getDisplayMetrics()

Answer (score 1):

`getResources()` is a method, but it return a object.
So, `getResources.getDisplayMetrics() = (return object).getDisplayMetrics()`.